# Failed to resolve component: q-card-title

Tags: quasar-framework

I'm new to the Quasar framework, I have a warning in the console when running my website:

> Failed to resolve component: q-card-title

Is there something I can do to correct it?

Comment: I don't think quasar v2 has a q-card-title component

Comment: Weird that if put one in the default app built then? But you're right I think.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your comment, but if you check q-card docs you 'll see it's just a bunch of <q-card-section>

Comment: q-card-title is for old quasar use q-card-section for new quasar